# Refactoring a XML_Unserializer reliant class to use DOMDocument

Tags: php, xml, dom, xml-deserialization

I have a class that takes this xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
    <pagedata> 
        <language>en-es</language> 
        <meta> 
            <![CDATA[
            <title>web page</title>
            ]]>
        </meta> 
        <pagecontent> 
            <class>test</class> 
                </pagecontent>
         </pagedata>
```

And uses XML_Unserializer to mutate this into an array. It becomes:

```
Array
(
    [language] => en-US
    [meta] => <title></title> 
    [pagecontent] => Array
        (
            [class] => test
)
```

I then have methods that return values of keys in the array. So for instance if I wanted the language I'd use `$class->getData('language')` or `$class->getData('pagecontent:class')`.

We no longer support PHP4 so I can now rely on native XML implementations. I have worked both with SimpleXML and the standard php DOM library. I prefer the latter since it's more powerful and flexible and simpleXML comes with certain caveats.

Since I have used the unserializer class, nearly all my methods interact with function methods such as `foreach`. I'm wondering if it's worth it to keep it an array, which would save me from refactoring all my methods? In addition, I know that it's sometimes a pain to grab the entire nodeValue of an element, because then you have to implement methods such as:

```
function innerHTML($node){
  $doc = new DOMDocument();
  foreach ($node->childNodes as $child)
    $doc->appendChild($doc->importNode($child, true));

  return $doc->saveHTML();
}
```

And it seems inefficient using that method many times over since it always creates a DOMDocument. I could probably refactor the method so it uses the same DOMDocument over and over and appends fragments but it seems overkill.

I would appreciate any input on this manner, in terms of whether I should even use the standard DOM lib and if so, should I refactor all my methods to use DOM functions or create an array and keep my methods as they are, in order to lower the chance of introducing new bugs?

Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, not sure if this is enough for an answer. Basically, if it works now and you dont have any performance and maintenance issues, I'd leave it as is. In any case, I'd make sure there is UnitTests before attempting refactoring. The UnitTests will dramatically lower the risk of introducing any new bugs when changing the code.

Comment: Our devs have been complaining about XML_Unserializer/PEAR so the request was put in to use native PHP5 methods.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use SimpleXML in your case since it's possible to keep the foreach loops with only few changes. It makes using XML simpler than using PHP's DOM itself. Accessing attributes is also easy with it.